# Heroku: http-error 410. Invalid response from API (I am not behind a proxy)

Tags: api, heroku, cmd

I am currently having some issues with heroku. I just installed it and tried to `heroku create`. It takes my credentials but so far i just get this

```
 !    HTTP Error: https://api.heroku.com/login 410 Gone
 !    Invalid response from API.
 !    HTTP 410
 !    {myMail myPw}
 !
 !    Are you behind a proxy?
 !    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy
```

I have been looking around for others with that issue but they all were behind a **proxy**. I am not. I also checked my firewall settings and also tried to run the command line client with admin rights. But nothing has proven to be successful so far. I'll keep trying and post an answer as soon as i figure it out. Maybe someone of you has an idea. Would be appreciated. Thanks in advance and

Greetings Chris

**EDIT**

Maybe some info. I'm running

> Windows 10 Pro (V10.0.15063)

and a basic network setup with a router and **DHCP**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had the same problem today.
When I type

```
heroku
```

in my Command Prompt, it promotes me to enter my email and after that my password. Then I got the same error message as you.
After that instead "heroku" I typed

```
heroku login
```

I entered the same email and password and everything was fine.

Comment: God, I'm behind a proxy, but this works perfectly for me:)

Comment: Alternatively, if 'heroku login' doesn't work, try the command 'heroku' first as the CLI might not be installed yet. Or you've installed an older version in the past that's interfering with things, so you should uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 4):

Ok. I made it work. Unfortunately I'm not really understanding why this worked which is pretty unsatisfying but I'll tell you what I did. I stumbled on some posts that were saying heroku-cli is outdated if that happens. First I tried to update it with npm using

```
npm update -g heroku-cli
```

which basically made heroku stop working alltogether because now the cli reported it needed node >7.X (and I was still running on 6.X). The node update I then made also didn't help because now heroku-cli was unable find the command bash.

In the end I just reinstalled heroku. After that (with at first getting the same error as in the beginning) I first did

```
heroku update
```

and after that `heroku login` worked. Now why I don't really grasp and maybe someone of you guys knows. But the version I had before `heroku update` was exaclty the same as afterwards

> heroku-cli/5.11.12-8ae9780 (windows-amd64) go1.7.5

Answer (score 0):

I found out the heroku.cl was blocked by my antivirus and unblocked it. Now its working flawless.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Heroku worked for me.

`heroku update`